# Como reutilizar un indice borrado de un TreeMap?

Tags: java

Como dice el título, quisiera saber la forma correcta (o mas sencilla) de "reutilizar" un indice, una vez que se borra una entrada en un TreeMap. Creo que a lo mejor esto no es algo que se haga, pero estoy aprendiendo, y quiero aprender la mejor forma de hacerlo. Actualmente lo hago del siguiente modo:

```
public class Equipo {
    TreeMap<Integer,Jugador> jugadores;
    String nombreEquipo;
    ArrayList<Integer> keysBorradas = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    public Equipo (String nombreEquipo){
        jugadores= new TreeMap<Integer,Jugador>();
        this.nombreEquipo=nombreEquipo;
    }
    public void nuevoJugador (Jugador actual) {
        if (keysBorradas.isEmpty()) {
            if (jugadores.isEmpty()) {
                jugadores.put(0,actual);
            }
            else jugadores.put((jugadores.lastKey()+1),actual);
        }
        else {
            jugadores.put(keysBorradas.get(0),actual);
            keysBorradas.remove(0);
        }
    }

    public void borrarJugador (Jugador actual) {
        for (Integer key:jugadores.keySet()) {
            if (jugadores.get(key)==actual){
                keysBorradas.add(key);
                jugadores.remove(actual);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "reutilizar un índice"?

Comment: Buenas, pues a que si añado por ejemplo 2 jugadores, tendría:
key: 0 , value: Jugador1
key: 1, value: Jugador2
Luego, al borrar por ejemplo Jugador1, el TreeMap jugadores quedaría:
key: 1, value: Jugador 2
Con lo que la key: 0 , ya no estaría en uso. Al ingresar un nuevo jugador al TreeMap, quiero que el siguiente entre "en una key borrada"(key:0 en este caso) prioritariamente, antes de en una nueva (key: 2)

Answer (score 2):

> Antes de todo, perdona mis faltas de español, no es mi lengua y estoy aquí para aprenderlo.

Para evitar iteraciones cada vez que añades o borras un jugador, es más sencillo utilizar un `TreeSet<Integer>` para guardar todos los números que estaban asignados a alguien que haya sido borrado, un `int` que guarde el proximo numero sin contar los que ya hayan sido borrados, y luego guardar el numero de cada jugador en la instancia de `Jugador` misma.

### 1 - Añadir el número al `Jugador`

```
public class Jugador {

    private int numero;           // <-- guardar el numero del jugador en el jugador mismo
    private final String nombre;

    Jugador(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

### 2 - Añadir un `TreeSet` y un `int` al `Equipo`

```
public class Equipo {
    TreeMap<Integer,Jugador> jugadores;
    String nombreEquipo;
    private final TreeSet<Integer> numerosDisponibles; // <-- para guardar todos los números que han sido asignados a algun jugador, pero que se han liberado
    private int proximoNumero; // <-- para guardar el próximo número por si no hubiera ningún número disponible en el TreeSet

    public Equipo (String nombreEquipo){
        jugadores= new TreeMap<>();
        this.nombreEquipo=nombreEquipo;
        numerosDisponibles = new TreeSet<>();
        this.proximoNumero = 0;
    }
}
```

### 3 - Función para calcular el proximo numero

```
private int getProximoNumero() {
    if (numerosDisponibles.isEmpty()) {     // <-- si no hay numeros disponibles
        return proximoNumero++;             // <-- devuelve el proximo y luego incrementalo para la proxima vez
    }
    return numerosDisponibles.pollFirst();  // <-- sino coge el primer número disponible desde el TreeSet ("poll" te lo coge y lo suprime del TreeSet)
}
```

### 4 - Lógica de numeración en `nuevoJugador()` y `borrarJugador()`

```
public void nuevoJugador (Jugador actual) {
    int numero = getProximoNumero(); // <-- Calcula el número para este jugador
    actual.setNumero(numero);        // <-- Guarda el número en el jugador también
    jugadores.put(numero, actual);   // <-- Guarda el jugador 
}

public void borrarJugador (Jugador actual) {
    int actualNumero = actual.getNumero();  // <-- Recupera el número del jugador
    jugadores.remove(actualNumero);         // <-- Suprime el jugador de tu equipo
    numerosDisponibles.add(actualNumero);   // <-- Añade su número a la lista de numeros que ahora están disponibles
}
```

### Ejemplo

```
    Equipo acMilan = new Equipo("A.C. Milan");
    acMilan.nuevoJugador(ibrahimovic);   // <-- numero 0
    acMilan.nuevoJugador(rebic);         // <-- numero 1
    acMilan.nuevoJugador(donnarumma);    // <-- numero 2
    acMilan.borrarJugador(ibrahimovic);  // <-- numero 0 vuelve a estar disponible
    acMilan.nuevoJugador(hernandez);     // <-- numero 0
    acMilan.nuevoJugador(paqueta);       // <-- numero 3
```

Resultado:

```
A.C. Milan
-----------
Numero: 0 - Nombre: Hernandez
Numero: 1 - Nombre: Rebic
Numero: 2 - Nombre: Donnarumma
Numero: 3 - Nombre: Paqueta
-----------
```